# What Oracle driver should I install in my MS SQL server to be able to use DTS to copy data from the Oracle server to the MS SQL server?

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, driver, dts

I have an **Oracle server** (version 9, I believe) and a **MS SQL server** (version 2000). The MS SQL server is running **MS Windows Server 2003**.

**I would like to use DTS to extract some data from the Oracle server and pour it into the MS SQL server.** I'm having problems finding out what driver I should install on my MS SQL server for it to be able to communicate with the Oracle server. (I don't really care if it's ODBC or a "native" Oracle driver.)

When I looked at this a while back I was stunned by the sheer number of different Oracle drivers and versions out there. **Any help with a direct link to the exact Oracle driver recommended would be greatly appreciated**, and I wouldn't mind any other helpful tips you could provide either. :) (Apart from upgrading the server/OS, that's not going to happen any time soon...)

I understand that it's the Instant Client that I'm being recommended to install, but more specifically for my situation, on the page http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/winsoft.html, are these the **two packages** I should install?

```
Version 11.1.0.6.0
```

*Because it's the latest version, and it should be able to connect to Oracle 9.*

```
Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications
```

*Because "all installations REQUIRE the Basic package", per information at the bottom of the Oracle webpage.*

```
Instant Client Package - ODBC: Additional libraries for enabling ODBC applications
```

*Because I need to use ODBC.*

**Have I understood this correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first choice would be the Instant Client: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/winsoft.html

Although this was not available for 9i, the 10g client will certainly connect to 9i without any problems, and the 11g probably would also.